# How do I fix the plot_models() error when I specify terms?

Tags: r, plot, graph

I've been following the instructions on this page: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/sjPlot/versions/2.8.10/topics/plot_models

I am using the following code:

```
data(efc)
# fit three models
fit1 <- lm(barthtot ~ c160age + c12hour + c161sex + c172code, data = efc)
fit2 <- lm(neg_c_7 ~ c160age + c12hour + c161sex + c172code, data = efc)
fit3 <- lm(tot_sc_e ~ c160age + c12hour + c161sex + c172code, data = efc)

# plot multiple models
plot_models(fit1, fit2, fit3, grid = TRUE)
```

I only want "carer' age" to show up. I tried doing the following:

```
plot_models(
  fit1, fit2, fit3,
  terms = c(
    "carer' age"
  ),
  m.labels = c("Barthel Index", "Negative Impact", "Services used"),
  show.values = FALSE, show.p = FALSE, p.shape = TRUE
)
```

I get the following error:

```
Error: Sorry, `model_parameters()` failed with the following error (possible class
  'character' not supported):

  $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

How do I fix this error? Any guidance will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The docs are a bit unclear as they mention a `terms` argument as the counterpart of `rm.terms`. However there is no `terms` argument and when using it is interpreted as another model via `...`. Instead you could use the `rm.terms` argument, which is a bit annoying but works:

```r
library(sjPlot)
#> #refugeeswelcome

data(efc)

fit1 <- lm(barthtot ~ c160age + c12hour + c161sex + c172code, data = efc)
fit2 <- lm(neg_c_7 ~ c160age + c12hour + c161sex + c172code, data = efc)
fit3 <- lm(tot_sc_e ~ c160age + c12hour + c161sex + c172code, data = efc)

plot_models(
    fit1, fit2, fit3,
    rm.terms = c(
      "c12hour", "c161sex", "c172code"
    ),
    m.labels = c("Barthel Index", "Negative Impact", "Services used"),
    show.values = FALSE, show.p = FALSE, p.shape = TRUE
  )
```

[image]